# jest mockImplementation always return undefined

Tags: jestjs

I'm making a test for a module. And I need to mock it. But the return value of mocked function always `undefined`. The following is my code.

```js
// foo.js
export const signin = () => {
  // some asynchronous code
  return Promise; // return a Promise value
};
```

```js
// MyReactComponent
// What I want to test
import { signin } from './foo';
const MyReactComponent = () => {
  // a function which called when the signin button was clicked
  const onClickSignin = async () => {
    ...
    const result = await signin(); // 'result' is always 'undefined'

    result.ok; // Error ! result is 'undefined'
    ...
  };
};
```

I tried two ways.

**First way**

```js
// MyReactComponent.test.js
import { signin } from './foo';
jest.mock('./foo', () => ({
  signin: jest.fn(() => true), // 'true' is just for checking if return undefined
}));

test('MyReactComponent', () => {
  ...
  expect(signin).matcher;
});
```

**Second way**

```js
// MyReactComponent.test.js
import { signin } from './foo';
jest.mock('./foo', () => ({
  signin: jest.fn(),
}));

test('MyReactComponent', () => {
  ...
  singin.mockImplementation(() => true); // 'true' is also for checking
  expect(signin).matcher;
});
```

How can I apply mock implementation for this case?
(The project environment is create-react-app called CRA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for it.
When we test a react component there is a `render` section in the test. And I wrote the `mockImplementation` after `render`.

```js
test('...', () => {
  const {...} = render(<MyReactComponent />);
  ...
  singin.mockImplementation(() => true);
});
```

So, after move the `mockImaplementation` at the before of the `render` line, the mocked function return correctly.

```js
test('...', () => {
  singin.mockImplementation(() => true); // move to here
  const {...} = render(<MyReactComponent />);
  ...
});
```